# Oracle 12c docker container -- uploading tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile, oracle12c, tnsnames

I'm creating a docker image of a oracle 12c and i want to include a custom tnsnames.ora file.

So what i do in my dockerfile:

- **COPY tnsnames.ora /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/xe/network/admin/**

But then i get an error like this:

- **rm: cannot remove '/u01/app/oracle/product': Is a directory**

Does somebody know what i'm doing wrong? And why does he want to remove the directory first?

Thanks in advance!

ps: i'm not a docker specialist :)

Comment: Try `COPY tnsnames.ora /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`

Comment: That didn't work 

`FROM sath89/oracle-12c

COPY tnsnames.ora /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/xe/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

This is my **dockerfile** at the moment.
Thanks for the suggestion!